# How to make a service only accessible from another service under the same app engine in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have an application deployed to google cloud app engine (flex environment). 
The application consists of two parts: FrontEnd (Angular) and BackEnd(Spring boot). 
Each one of these applications is deployed to a different service under the same app engine. 
Is there any way to apply a firewall rule to the BackEnd service to deny all requests except the ones coming from the FrontEnd service? 
Note: I have many services under the same app engine, so I need to apply the rule only to one service so that other services will not be affected.

Comment: Hi. A feature request was created for this matter. Check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110763628

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that currently as the App Engine firewall will affect all your services, dispatch.yaml will not prevent clients from accessing your project using [project_name].appspot.com and adding network in [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#network_settings) settings will only have effect in context of that network.

One [workaround](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services) could be to set a different project and allowing access there only from another Google Cloud Project. Otherwise you can set checking authentication on the background instances using service accounts.